# Why is TIMESTAMP column always zero after updating using Node JS?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

```
query("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `discount_codes` (`discount_code` VARCHAR(50), `expirationDate` TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, `claimedBy` VARCHAR(15), `type` TEXT)")

exports.claimDiscount = function(code, user) {
    var queryString = "UPDATE discount_codes SET expirationDate=NOW(), claimedBy = ? WHERE discount_code = ?"
    try{
        query(queryString, [user, code])
    } catch(err){
        console.log(err)
    }
}
```

The column is always 0000-00-00 00:00:00, both on insert query and update query, the other column is updated correctly. I have no idea what I am doing wrong, punching my head in wall for hours because of this. Any help is really appreciated

Comment: What do you expect your `ON UPDATE` clause to do?

Comment: It should display the current date on expirationDate

Comment: Please show your table schema

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing some parentheses.

Use `TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()` instead of `TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`